# Remove index.php?dir= from URL?

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect

I have a link structure like

```
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=first/
http://www.example.com/folder/index.php?dir=first/second/
```

and so on..

I would like to hide the `index.php?dir=` so the URLs appear human friendly.

Please help me set-up the htaccess?

Comment: Your question is too specific to your problem, you may get more answers that will help you if you change the question to something like 'How do you rewrite a URL using an htaccess file?'

Comment: I suggest using Google. These `.htaccess` rewrite rules are quite easy to find some resources on. I'm sure there are a thousand similar questions here on SO as well.

Comment: when you use GET you'll see the parameters in the URL, using POST will not display them. Regarding index.php - both GET/POST will display it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty rudimentary setup for .htaccess & mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite if the file or directory actually exists
# protects against a rewrite loop if index.php is hit
# and allows css, js, images not to be messed with
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite everything to the dir=parameter, appending any existing querystring with QSA
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should enable urls like

- `http://example.com/first`
- `http://example.com/first/second`

Comment: Make sure to put the .htacess file in the folder "folder" where you have index.php.

Comment: Have already tried this! Doesn't works!! Removing the index.php?dir= from URL tries to open the directory directory which ofcourse doesn't exists..

Comment: Figured it out! Had to remove 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d' from the above rewrite..